# Logical And Not Working in Custom PowerShell Class

Tags: powershell

I'm porting some logic to PowerShell from C which extensively uses an 8-bit data type, and frequently assigns larger values/smaller values then it can hold, and relies on the value being assigned is the 8 remaining bits of data that fit.

To replicate this in PowerShell I've created a custom type which is working the way I want except for logical and. If PowerShell follows the guidance on .NET operator overloading [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading#overloadable-operators)

> Conditional logical operators cannot be overloaded. However, if a type
> with the overloaded true and false operators also overloads the & or |
> operator in a certain way, the && or || operator, respectively, can be
> evaluated for the operands of that type.

I have provided the "&" with op_BitwiseAnd and "|" with op_BitwiseOr, However I have not been able to work out how to overload the true and false operators, which I believe I also need to do.

This code outputs

```
True 
False
```

But expected output should be:

```
False
False
```

The current code:

```
class UInt8 : System.IComparable,System.IConvertible,System.IFormattable
{
    Hidden [Byte]$m_value
    
    UInt8() { $this.m_value = 0 }
    UInt8([Int]$value) { $this.m_value = [Uint8]::HandleOVerflow($value) }

    static [UInt8]DefaultToType()
    {
        return New-Object UInt8
    }

    Hidden static [Byte]HandleOverflow([Object]$n)
    {
        while ($n -gt [Byte]::MaxValue) { $n = $n -([Byte]::MaxValue+1) }
        while ($n -lt [Byte]::MinValue) { $n = ([Byte]::MaxValue+1) + $n }        
        return $n
    }
    
    [String]ToString()
    {
        return $this.m_value.ToString()
    }

    
    [String]ToString([IFormatProvider]$provider)
    {
        return $this.m_value.ToString($provider)
    }

    [String]ToString([string]$format)
    {

        return $this.m_value.ToString($format)
    }
   
    [String]ToString([String]$format, [IFormatProvider]$provider) {
        return $this.m_value.ToString($format,$provider)
    }
    
    [TypeCode]GetTypeCode() 
    {
            return [TypeCode]::Byte
    }

    [Char]ToChar([IFormatProvider]$provider)
    {
        return [Convert]::ToChar($this.m_value)
    }

    [Byte]ToByte([IFormatProvider]$provider)
    {
        return [Convert]::ToByte($this.m_value)
    }

    [SByte]ToSByte([IFormatProvider]$provider)
    {
        return [Convert]::ToSByte($this.m_value)
    }

    [Bool]ToBoolean([IFormatProvider]$provider)
    {
        return [Convert]::ToBoolean($this.m_value)
    }

    [Int16]ToInt16([IFormatProvider]$provider)
    {
        return [Convert]::ToInt16($this.m_value)
    }

    [UInt16]ToUInt16([IFormatProvider]$provider)
    {
        return [Convert]::ToUInt16($this.m_value)
    }

    [Int32]ToInt32([IFormatProvider]$provider)
    {
        return [Convert]::ToInt32($this.m_value)
    }

    [UInt32]ToUInt32([IFormatProvider]$provider)
    {
        return [Convert]::ToUInt32($this.m_value)
    }

    [Int64]ToInt64([IFormatProvider]$provider)
    {
        return [Convert]::ToInt64($this.m_value)
    }

    [UInt64]ToUInt64([IFormatProvider]$provider)
    {
        return [Convert]::ToUInt64($this.m_value)
    }

    [Single]ToSingle([IFormatProvider]$provider)
    {
        return [Convert]::ToSingle($this.m_value)
    }

    [Double]ToDouble([IFormatProvider]$provider)
    {
        return [Convert]::ToDouble($this.m_value)
    }

    [Decimal]ToDecimal([IFormatProvider]$provider)
    {
        return [Convert]::ToDecimal($this.m_value)
    }

    [DateTime]ToDateTime([IFormatProvider]$provider) 
    {
        throw [System.InvalidCastException] "Invalid Cast from UInt8 to DateTime"
    }
    
    [Object]ToType([Type]$type, [IFormatProvider]$provider) 
    {
        return [Convert]::DefaultToType($this, $type, $provider)
    }

    static [UInt8] op_Assign([UInt8] $a) 
    { 
        return $a
    }
      
    static [UInt8] op_Assign([Object] $a) 
    { 
        return New-Object UInt8([UInt8]::HandleOverflow($a))
    }

    static [UInt8] op_Addition([UInt8] $a, [UInt8] $b) 
    { 
        $result = $a.m_value + $b.m_value
        return New-Object UInt8([UInt8]::HandleOverflow($result))
    }

    static [UInt8] op_Addition([UInt8] $a, [Object] $b) 
    { 
        $result = $a.m_value + $b
        return New-Object UInt8([UInt8]::HandleOverflow($result))
    }
    
    static [UInt8] op_Subtraction([UInt8] $a, [Object] $b) 
    { 
        $result = $a.m_value - $b
        return New-Object UInt8([UInt8]::HandleOverflow($result))
    }

    static [UInt8] op_Subtraction([UInt8] $a, [UInt8] $b) 
    { 
        $result = $a.m_value - $b.m_value
        return New-Object UInt8([UInt8]::HandleOverflow($result))
    }
    
    static [UInt8] op_Multiply([UInt8] $a, [Object] $b) 
    { 
        $result = $a.m_value * $b
        return New-Object UInt8([UInt8]::HandleOverflow($result))
    }

    static [UInt8] op_Multiply([UInt8] $a, [UInt8] $b) 
    { 
        $result = $a.m_value * $b.m_value
        return New-Object UInt8([UInt8]::HandleOverflow($result))
    }
    
    static [Uint8] op_Modulus([UInt8] $a, [Object] $b)
    {
        $result = $a.m_value % $b
        return New-Object UInt8($result)
    }
        
    static [Uint8] op_Modulus([UInt8] $a, [UInt8] $b)
    {
        $result = $a.m_value % $b.m_value
        return New-Object UInt8($result)
    }

    static [Uint8] op_ExclusiveOr([UInt8] $a, [Object] $b)
    {
        $result = $a.m_value -bxor $b
        return New-Object UInt8([UInt8]::HandleOverflow($result))
    }

    static [Uint8] op_ExclusiveOr([UInt8] $a, [UInt8] $b)
    {
        $result = $a.m_value -bxor $b.m_value
        return New-Object UInt8($result)
    }

    static [Uint8] op_BitwiseAnd([UInt8] $a, [Object] $b)
    {
            $result = $a.m_value -band $b
            return New-Object UInt8([UInt8]::HandleOverflow($result))
    }

    static [Uint8] op_BitwiseAnd([UInt8] $a, [UInt8] $b)
    {
            $result = $a.m_value -band $b.m_value
            return New-Object UInt8($result)
    }

    static [Uint8] op_BitwiseOr([UInt8] $a, [Object] $b)
    {
            $result = $a.m_value -bor $b
            return New-Object UInt8([UInt8]::HandleOverflow($result))
    }

    static [Uint8] op_BitwiseOr([UInt8] $a, [UInt8] $b)
    {
            $result = $a.m_value -bor $b.m_value
            return New-Object UInt8($result)
    }
    [int] CompareTo([object] $other) {
      if ($this.m_value -eq $other.m_value) {return 0 }
      if ($this.m_value -lt $other.m_value) {return -1 }
      return 1 # -gt
    }

    [bool] Equals([object] $other) {
      return $this.m_value -eq $other.m_value
    }
  
    [int] GetHashCode() {
      return $this.m_value.GetHashCode()
    }

}

[UInt8]$v1 = 0
[UInt8]$v2 = 1

[Byte]$b1 = 0
[Byte]$b2 = 1

$v1 -and $v2
$b1 -and $b2
```

This is on Windows 11 in PowerShell ISE

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value                                                              
----                           -----                                                              
PSVersion                      5.1.22000.282                                                      
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                            
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                            
BuildVersion                   10.0.22000.282                                                     
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                    
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```